# Inno Setup - IIS Application pool with Custom Account

Tags: iis, installation, inno-setup

I have been trying to figure out how to install and register IIS using an Inno Setup Script using Custom Identity.

In identity option, I am using custom account but I don't know how to pass account info (username and password).

Comment: Please first write a PowerShell script to perform the configuration, and then call it from your Pascal Script. Other interfaces (ADSI/WMI) used by Pascal Script are too old to be used.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I will try this.